# get subset of dataframe and name each sub-dataframe differently using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I am working with python.

I have a dataframe and I want to get subset of it.
I also want the subset of dataframe differently.

All I could find out so far as was,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':list('aabbef'),
               'A':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
               'B':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
               'C':[1,3,5,7,1,0]}, columns = ['Name','A','B','C'])

print (df)
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby('Name')))
print (d)
print (d['a'])
```

In the above example, I could get a subset of dataframe using a specific value in Name column.

I wonder is there any way that I could assign different names for each of subsets.

For example, in the above case, there are 4 different values in Name column (a,b,e,f).

If I have 26 valaues (a,b,c, ..., z) and I generate a list of names for each sub-dataframe, qqq = [q1, q2, q3, q4, ... q26],
I want to get,

```
q1 = d['a']
q2 = d['b']
q3 = d['e']
q4 = d['f']

...

q26 = d['z']
```

Is there any way that I could use loop for this name assignment?

Thank you!

#

Thank you for the comments.

The data I am working with now looks like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do8HM.png)

For each ID, there are 15 more questions and for each question there are two to three answers. Now, the data is stacked (I would say as a long shape).

What I want is to transform the data into wide shape.
For each ID, I want quetion + answer varaible as a column.

What I have thought initially is that,

I generate a new column ('hca_qa') concatenating question and answer column.
Then I get the subset of dataframe by 'hca_qa'. 
Then I merge the subsets of dataframe into one to get a wide shape data.

So far, I know how to get a subset of dafaframes, but to merge them into one, I may need a name for each dataframe and then merge them.

I am open to a better way so please let me know.

I am sincerely appreciate.

Comment: Why do you want to create many separate objects? Use containers like the dictionary you already use to manage **one** not 26 similar objects. Keep global environment uncluttered! You lose no functionality if dataframe is stored in dict/list than by itself: `d['a'].describe()`, `d['b'].head()`, `d['c'].tail()`.

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem. Why do you want to have so much different `df`s stored in variables? What is the bigger problem you are trying to solve?